# How to extract html between two different tags in python?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I have the following html:

```
<h2>blah</h2>
html content to extract 
(here can come tags, nested structures too, but no top-level h2)
<h2>other blah</h2>
```

Can I extract the content without using `string.split("<h2>")` in python?
(Say, with BeautifulSoup or with some other library?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some test code using HTQL from http://htql.net:

```
sample="""<h2>blah</h2>
        html content to extract 
        <div>test</div>
        <h2>other blah<h2>
    """

import htql
htql.query(sample, "<h2 sep excl>2")
# [('\n        html content to extract \n        <div>test</div>\n        ',)]

htql.query(sample, "<h2 sep> {a=<h2>:tx; b=<h2 sep excl>2 | a='blah'} ")
# [('blah', '\n        html content to extract \n        <div>test</div>\n        ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

With BeautifulSoup, use the [`.next_siblings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) iterable to get to text following a tag:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> sample = '<h2>blah</h2>\nhtml content to extract\n<h2>other blah<h2>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> print ''.join(takewhile(lambda e: isinstance(e, NavigableString), soup.h2.next_siblings))

html content to extract
```

This finds all text elements following the `soup.h2` element and joins them into one string.

Comment: +1, ok, so basically I do a next_sibling iteration until I reach the next h2?

Comment: Exactly; the `takewhile()` call here loops over siblings as long as they are instances of `NavigableString`, and the next sibling that is *not* a string is the `H2` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a bit more robust solution:

```
def get_chunk_after_tag(tag):
    """ tag is a tag element in a bs4 soup.
    """
    result = ''
    for elem in tag.next_siblings:
        if isinstance(elem, bs4.Tag) and elem.name == tag.name:
            break
        result += str(elem)
    return result
```

For extracting text from `<hX>` to `<hX>`. It is easily modified to extract text from a tag to another.